# Using ActionListener with JButton

Tags: action, jbutton, actionlistener, java1.4

So, I am kind of new to programming interfaces with java.  I have a menu of JButtons, where each JButton has an action associated with it (so I use new JButton(action)), however once a button is selected, I want to close the menu, so I have an ActionListener attached to each JButton that does that.

For prettiness reasons, I would like it if the ActionListener went before the JButton's action, but I cannot find a way to do that does not involve adding a new thread or creating a new class...  Does anyone have any ideas?  Also, I am using Java 1.4, so none of the fancy new stuff.

Comment: that's the default behaviour of menuItems in a meny, so why do you use JButton instead? Don't re-invent the wheel :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative, reliable approach, using an inner class - I know you didn't want to create your own class but this keeps it quite simple.

```
class MenuAction extends Action {
    public void actionPerformed() { /* close menu */ }
}

public void MyMenu() { // or where your menu construction code occurs
    ...
    JButton mybutton1 =
        new JButton(new MenuAction() {
                public void performAction() {
                    // close the menu first
                    super.actionPerformed();
                    // then perform the button's action
                    /* button1's behaviour */
                }
            });
    ...
```

Comment: Yep, I basically ended up doing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: *deemed incorrect due to there being no guarrantee on the order in which added actions are performed - see comments*

Action can be assigned using a function:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setAction%28javax.swing.Action%29

Rather than passing it in via the constructor, just assign it afterwards:

```
ActionListener closeMenu = ...;
Action myaction1 = ...;
JButton mybutton1 = new JButton();
mybutton1.addActionListener(closeMenu);
mybutton1.setAction(myaction1);
```

Code is pseudo/untested, but that's the first thing I would try.

Comment: I did post first time using ActionListener/addActionListener for both closeMenu/myaction1 but that's probably not going to exactly replicate the 'new JButton(Action)' behaviour. Fixed!

Comment: So since I want the menu to close and then the action to occur, should I set the listener to myaction1 and the actually action to closeMenu?  Or will it just perform whatever action is added first (in this case the listener?).

Comment: Try it and see :-) experimentation is often the best way to discover when coding.  (I believe it is the first added Action/ActionListener that will be performed first.)  Let me know if it works!

Comment: In fact, you could probably do it both ways.  It depends what you feel is cleanest.  I think closeMenu as an ActionListener and myaction1 as an Action is the cleanest approach, but that is your call.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying, I just have super long compile times xD

Comment: How did you get on, did it work?  For solving long compile times I suggest using an IDE that compiles on-the-fly such as Eclipse.

Comment: -1: notification sequence of listeners is undefined! Even if it might look like working at some time, there's no guarantee whatever that it will keep working

Comment: Yeah, basically what kleopatra said, I have learned that the ordering is kind of random so I need to find a way to make it either just one action or just make a new class.  Sadly, while I do use it, eclipse can't cross-compile.

Comment: Ok, well the answer is a bit simple then.  Will post as a new answer.